# Google Maps Android: hide Points Of Interest (Styling doesn't work)

Tags: android, google-maps

So I'm working with a maps activity in android studio with some overlays and my own markers and the standard location markers of Google Maps ([like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjWMw.png)) are in the way. Now I want to remove them and I tried to do it via styling without result. I used the online styling wizard by Google and copied the JSON in a string that I than used to set as a style, but I still see the standard points of interest. Is there another way to hide them, or did I do something wrong (new to JSON)?

**Java code to set the style (in the OnReady method):**

```
mMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.style_json)));
```

**JSON file in string resource:**

```
 <resources>
    <string name="style_json">
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.line",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e5e5e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "transit.station",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#c9c9c9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
    </string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use JSON file with styles directly, not `String` resource with JSON characters:

1. create JSON file **src\main\res\raw\empty_map_style.json** like this:

```json
[
  {
    featureType: "poi",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      {
        visibility: "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2. add map style to your `GoogleMap`

```java
mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.empty_map_style));
```

That should work.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. Just one heads up for anyone that ever has the same problem. getContext() didn't get recognized, but I used getApplicationContext() and it worked fine.

Comment: I would love to, but I don't have enough points apperently. I'm sorry.

Comment: @NDT You can't up-vote, but you can accept the answer by click on gray "check box" under vote score.