# Google Maps Android - Hide Points of Interest on the Satellite map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'd like to display a map using the `GoogleMap` class from the Google Play Services SDK, and have it use the `satellite` map type without displaying Points of Interest.

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62912199/google-maps-android-hide-points-of-interest-styling-doesnt-work) very similar question, but that question uses Custom Map Styles to hide the POI and, as described in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/hiding-features), "Styling only works on the `normal` map type".

Does anyone know of a workaround/method for hiding POI on a Satellite Google Map?

I'm looking for the equivalent of [`showsPointsOfInterest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452102-showspointsofinterest) from MapKit.